# Optimising a Firestore query within a Firestore query

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I get a small list of documents from a Firestore collection (max. 10). With each one of those documents I check another collection to see if that particular document exists. Due to using a NoSQL database my data is stored in two separate collections.

However, when running this query it is still taking 3-4 seconds to complete. I'm wondering if there is any way I can optimise this without changing my data structure?

### CODE

```
export const getOffers = async (id, uid) => {
  const ref = collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "venues", id, "offers");
  const q = query(
    ref,
    where("active", "==", true),
    orderBy("reusable", "desc"),
    limit(10)
  );
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const promises = snapshot.docs.map(async (document) => {
    const ref = doc(
      FIREBASE_FIRESTORE,
      "users",
      uid,
      "redemptions",
      document.id
    );
    const redemptionSnapshot = await getDoc(ref);
    return {
      id: document.id,
      used: redemptionSnapshot.exists(),
      ...document.data(),
    };
  });
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  return data;
};
```

### ADDING TIME STATS

```
export const getOffers = async (id, uid) => {
  const startFirst = performance.now();
  const ref = collection(FIREBASE_FIRESTORE, "venues", id, "offers");
  const q = query(
    ref,
    where("active", "==", true),
    orderBy("reusable", "desc"),
    limit(10)
  );
  const snapshot = await getDocs(q);
  const endFirst = performance.now();
  console.log("FIRST CALL TAKES: " + (endFirst - startFirst) + " MILLISECONDS");
  const startSecond = performance.now();
  const promises = snapshot.docs.map(async (document) => {
    const ref = doc(
      FIREBASE_FIRESTORE,
      "users",
      uid,
      "redemptions",
      document.id
    );
    const redemptionSnapshot = await getDoc(ref);
    const endSecond = performance.now();
    console.log(
      "SECOND CALL TAKES: " + (endSecond - startSecond) + " MILLISECONDS"
    );
    return {
      id: document.id,
      used: redemptionSnapshot.exists(),
      ...document.data(),
    };
  });
  const data = await Promise.all(promises);
  return data;
};

FIRST CALL TAKES: 1306.4292080402374 MILLISECONDS
SECOND CALL TAKES: 1313.7304170131683 MILLISECONDS
```

All are around the same times between 1300-1500ms.

Comment: Firstly, how are you benchmarking this?  I don't see any log lines that show where the timing begins and ends. Without that, it's not clear what you're actually measuring.  If you add log lines at each stage and share the output, that would help everyone agree on what is actually happening here.  Secondly, it's possible you just have a slow connection, and there's nothing we can do about that.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added time logs, internet connection is good.

Comment: Where are you located?  Where is your Firestore instance located?  How is the connection between those two locations? There is nothing you can do code-wise to improve performance.  You need a better overall connection, or move closer to the data.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm in Tbilisi, Georgia instance located @ europe-central2 which I believe is the closest geographically. Will re-think the data structure as waiting this long for what essentially is a "Detail Screen" is not a good UX.